# AJAX, Live input validation after entering a specific number of characters

Tags: javascript, android, ajax, validation, keyboard

I've used this code to do input validation immediately after entering the third character, where the "captchacode" shows only three characters, but this code
does not work all the time.

```
$('#captchacode').keyup( function(e){
     if ($(this).val().length >= 3) { /*DO VALIDATION*/ }
}
```

It's not compatible with all browers - Chrome /desktop + jelly beans + Safari/ IOS works fine, But Chrome /Lollipop does not work.

---

I've found that the browser has nothing to do with this issue, its all about the "Keyboard" so go to "Play Store" and install "Google Keyboard", then from your mobile settings change you default "Keyboard" to "Google Keyboard" and this will solve this issue.

Comment: Looks fine to me, should work. If it does not it would be interesting to look if there are any javascript errors shown or what `$(this)` actually evaluates to...

Comment: ($this) is evaluate to ('#captchacode')

Comment: Sure that it does not evaluate to an object? If it really resolves to that string (whyever), then certainly a call to `val()` must fail... But somehow I doubt that. Try to dig deeper: it probably resolves to an object. Check if the method `val()` is defined, if so what it returns, ...

Comment: I've tried to change the $(this) but no luck

Comment: [Live Email Checking](http://www.sanwebe.com/assets/ajax-username-live-check/) This link has a demo for Live email check

Comment: Sorry, but I am not interested in "Live Email Checking", I have no idea where that link leads to and I will not try it.

Comment: About the problem discussed here, sorry I did not give that hint before, looks like you are not aware of that: use your browsers development console (usually key F12, but that depends on your browser, or right click somewhere and chose "Inspect element"). In that console you can see any javascript errors in a live manner, also you can directly enter javascript commands in the "console" tab like `console.log($(this))`. The result is what you are interested in. So is it a string or an object? If an object, does the method `val()` exist in it? If so, ... (you get the idea) Happy coding!